# why at django framework vscode extension pylance giving me reed line at path

Tags: python, django

If I write the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("/", views.home, name='home')
    path("about", views.about, name='about')
    path("services", views.services, name='services')
    path("about", views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

[VS Code marks the second `path` function with a red line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx4I9.jpg)

what can be the problem here?

Comment: Just disable Django extension. It sometimes gives weird errors like this one. I was caught once when writing html code.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote is *incorrect*: you are working with a list, and you should use commas between the different paths, so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("/", views.home, name='home'),  # ← comma
    path("about", views.about, name='about'),  # ← comma
    path("services", views.services, name='services'),  # ← comma
    path("about", views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

other problems are that you do not use a slash at the end (this is not mandatory, but is advisable). Finally two of your paths have the same name, so likely the one with `about` should be `contact`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("/", views.home, name='home'),
    path("about/", views.about, name='about'),
    path("services/", views.services, name='services'),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
   path("/", views.home, name='home')
   path("about", views.about, name='about'),
   path("services", views.services, name='services')
   path("about", views.contact, name='contact')
```

]

Your problem is you need to add  (coma)" , " after all path function.
A
and You need to change Your last path "about/" to "contact/" .

This is right:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
   path("/", views.home, name='home')
   path("about/", views.about, name='about'),
   path("services/", views.services, name='services')
   path("contact/", views.contact, name='contact')
```

]